# Ajax variable not posted to the php page

Tags: php, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem posting from ajax elements.

I created a php page that reads some data from the database and renders a html page with a table inside. The user can modify the values in the table and submit the changes to the database.

Everything worked fine, but I needed to dynamically update the content of part of html table. So, I put a tbody element in the page and used a js function to load elements inside the tbody element. My js function uses a `XMLHttpRequest` object to call another php page. The second php page reads the database filtering the data by the input posted variables and creates a html table that is sent back to the first php page. It works perfectly, my html table is filled with data dynamically read from the database.

My problem is when I try to submit the data changed in the table: I can read with the _REQUEST all elements of the first php page but not the section created with ajax so I can't update my database. If I check the content posted to the second page, I can see that the table section is not posted at all. Also, in the first page I can read the elements ID and NAME of the table with a js script, so they are in the first page but they are not posted to the second page.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Use a debugger and see what you're sending back in the actual request.

Comment: please edit in the whole XMLHttpRequest function